# Android button onclick doesn't work

Tags: android, button, onclick

i'm having trouble with my trivia application, it can display the first question but when i click the answers (button) nothing happened. when the answer button is clicked, user will get score and total answer will be added. However, if the user choose the incorrect answer user still move to the next question.

```
public class play extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
private Question currentQuestion;
private int currentQuestionIndex;
private ArrayList<Button> questionButton;
private TextView questionstextview;
private TextView questionnumber;
private TextView playerfeedback;
public static TextView displayscore;
public static int score;
private List<Question> QuestionList;
private int answerchoice; 
public static int totalanswer;
public static int correctanswer;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.play);
        Log.i("playclass", "this is play class running");

        questionButton = new ArrayList<Button>();

        questionButton.add((Button) findViewById (R.id.answerbutton1));
        questionButton.add((Button) findViewById (R.id.answerbutton2));
        questionButton.add((Button) findViewById (R.id.answerbutton3));
        questionButton.add((Button) findViewById (R.id.answerbutton4));
        currentQuestion = null;
        currentQuestionIndex = 0;

        View AnswerButton1 = findViewById(R.id.answerbutton1);
        AnswerButton1.setOnClickListener(this);
        View AnswerButton2 = findViewById(R.id.answerbutton2);
        AnswerButton2.setOnClickListener(this);
        View AnswerButton3 = findViewById(R.id.answerbutton3);
        AnswerButton3.setOnClickListener(this);
        View AnswerButton4 = findViewById(R.id.answerbutton4);
        AnswerButton4.setOnClickListener(this);

        Log.i("playclass", "aftersetlistener");

        QuestionList = new ArrayList<Question>();
        ArrayList <String> answer = new ArrayList<String>();

        answer.add("8");
        answer.add("9");
        answer.add("3");
        answer.add("1");
        QuestionList.add(new Question("what is 4+4", answer, 0));
        answer.add("17");
        answer.add("20");
        answer.add("15");
        answer.add("14");
        QuestionList.add(new Question("what is 7+8?", answer, 3));
        answer.add("20");
        answer.add("30");
        answer.add("19");
        answer.add("34");
        QuestionList.add(new Question("what is 10+10?", answer, 0));
        answer.add("12");
        answer.add("11");
        answer.add("13");
        answer.add("14");
        QuestionList.add(new Question("what is 6+6?", answer, 0));
        answer.add("6");
        answer.add("5");
        answer.add("4");
        answer.add("7");
        QuestionList.add(new Question("what is 4+3?", answer, 3));
        answer.add("7");
        answer.add("9");
        answer.add("10");
        answer.add("11");
        QuestionList.add(new Question("what is 3+7?", answer, 2));

        questionstextview = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.questionstextview);           
        questionnumber = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.questionnumber);        
        displayscore = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.displayscore);

        StartTrivia();
    }

public void ButtonPress (View answerButton){
    Log.i("playclass", "after View answerButton ");
    MediaPlayer soundfx = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.click);

    soundfx.start();

    Log.i("playclass", "after soundfx ");
    for (int i=0; i< questionButton.size(); i++)

        if (questionButton.get(i) ==answerButton)

        if (i==currentQuestion.getAnswerIndex()){
            Log.i("playclass", "before adding score,total answer and correctanswer ");
             score=+5;
             totalanswer++;
             correctanswer++;
             Log.i("playclass", "after adding score,total answer and correctanswer ");

            displayscore.setText(Integer.toString(score));

            Log.i("playclass", "after display score/setscore to integer ");

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

             Log.i("playclass", "after correct toast ");
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             Log.i("playclass", "after incorrect toast");
        }

            currentQuestionIndex++;
             Log.i("playclass", "after currentQuestionIndex++; ");

            if (currentQuestionIndex < QuestionList.size()){
                Log.i("playclass", "after currentQuestionIndex < QuestionList.size() ");
                StartTrivia();
                Log.i("playclass", "after StartTrivia in if statement ");
            }
            else{
                Intent result = new Intent (this, finalscreen.class);
                startActivity(result);
                Log.i("playclass", "after IntentResult ");
            }
}

public void StartTrivia(){
    Log.i("playclass", "running StartTrivia() " + currentQuestion); 

    currentQuestion = QuestionList.get(currentQuestionIndex); 
    Log.i("playclass", "after get current question " + currentQuestion);
    questionstextview.setText(currentQuestion.getquestion());
    Log.i("playclass", "after set current question");
    questionnumber.setText(Integer.toString(currentQuestionIndex+1));
    Log.i("playclass", "after convert int to string for question number");
    for (int i = 0; i < questionButton.size(); i++)
     { 
        Log.i("playclass", "before get question button");
        Log.i("playclass", "before currentQuestion " + i + currentQuestion.getanswer());
         String ans = currentQuestion.getanswer().get(i); 
         questionButton.get(i).setText(ans);
         Log.i("playclass", "after get question button");
     }
    } <br><br>
```

**Play XML Buttons**

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/answerbutton1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="ButtonPress"
        android:text="Button" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/answerbutton2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="ButtonPress"
        android:text="Button" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/answerbutton3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="ButtonPress"
        android:text="Button" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/answerbutton4"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="ButtonPress"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout><br><br>
```

**The LogCat**

08-12 14:11:26.853: I/playclass(330): this is play class running
08-12 14:11:26.853: I/playclass(330): aftersetlistener
08-12 14:11:26.873: I/playclass(330): running StartTrivia() null
08-12 14:11:26.873: I/playclass(330): after get current question
 com.example.quizgame.Question@408feec8
 
08-12 14:11:26.873: I/playclass(330): after set current question
 
08-12 14:11:26.873: I/playclass(330): after convert int to string for question number
 
08-12 14:11:26.873: I/playclass(330): before get question button
 
08-12 14:11:26.873: I/playclass(330): before currentQuestion 0[8, 9, 3, 1, 17, 20, 15, 14, 20, 30, 19, 34, 12, 11, 13, 14, 6, 5, 4, 7, 7, 9, 10, 11]
 
08-12 14:11:26.883: I/playclass(330): after get question button
 
08-12 14:11:26.883: I/playclass(330): before get question button
 
08-12 14:11:26.883: I/playclass(330): before currentQuestion 1[8, 9, 3, 1, 17, 20, 15, 14, 20, 30, 19, 34, 12, 11, 13, 14, 6, 5, 4, 7, 7, 9, 10, 11]
 
08-12 14:11:26.883: I/playclass(330): after get question button
 
08-12 14:11:26.883: I/playclass(330): before get question button
 
08-12 14:11:26.883: I/playclass(330): before currentQuestion 2[8, 9, 3, 1, 17, 20, 15, 14, 20, 30, 19, 34, 12, 11, 13, 14, 6, 5, 4, 7, 7, 9, 10, 11]
 
08-12 14:11:26.883: I/playclass(330): after get question button
 
08-12 14:11:26.883: I/playclass(330): before get question button
 
08-12 14:11:26.893: I/playclass(330): before currentQuestion 3[8, 9, 3, 1, 17, 20, 15, 14, 20, 30, 19, 34, 12, 11, 13, 14, 6, 5, 4, 7, 7, 9, 10, 11]
 
08-12 14:11:26.893: I/playclass(330): after get question button
 
08-12 14:11:27.423: I/ActivityManager(74): Displayed com.example.quizgame/.play: +722ms

Comment: Just to make sure, is the xml you posted play.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `android:onclick` in the XML, you don't need to set an OnClickListener for the button in code. Remove all the `setOnClickListener()` stuff in your code and also the `implements OnClickListener` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Please dont use the

```
android:onClick="ButtonPress"
```

from XML file.

If you want to use multiple buttons use it this way:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private final static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    Button sendButton, otherButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
        sendButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        otherButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.otherButton);
        otherButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.sendButton:
                // do something with the button click
                break;

            case R.id.otherButton:
                // do something
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This way you avoid strange behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

You need not use android:onClick="ButtonPress"
you can use the following code directly for each button

```
answerbutton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //your code for the particular button 
            }
        });
```